# Graphviz Angular app ERROR: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word

Tags: angular, d3.js, graphviz, webassembly

I am trying to run graphviz in Angular.
I also tried to run demo in [d3-graphviz-angular](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz-angular)

but I always get same error and graph is not shown.
Any idea where is problem or what am I doing wrong?
I pulled repo, run npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
then ng serve.

d3 and wasm versions from npm list:
d3-graphviz@3.1.0, @hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.13

Console log:
[image]

`core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 2e 2e 2f 2e @+0). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info. RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 2e 2e 2f 2e @+0). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info. at abort (index.es6.js:150) at index.es6.js:150 at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391) at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150) at zone.js:889 at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423) at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422) at resolvePromise (zone.js:831) at zone.js:896 at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423) at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290) at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422) at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195) at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)`

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Can you let us know what version of Angular you are using?  My GraphViz code works in Angular 12, but fails in Angular 13. I have not resolved yet, but seems related

Answer (score 0):

I think it will solve your problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKnn0Ujdz0o